# C# Improve Progressbar Accuracy for File Processing

Tags: c#, progress-bar

In my code, I'm processing a very large number of files and I'm trying to implement a more accurate progress display in my app. Because the files vary so much (1-250MB) in size, and therefore processing time, simply using a counter of files processed doesn't give an accurate representation of the progress.

```
progress?.Report((i+1) * 100 / total);
```

Instead, I looked at factoring in the file size with this approach:

```
progress?.Report(pb.Value + (int)(update.Size * 100 / totalSize));
```

But, upon completion, the progressbar isn't full which I presume is due to the loss of precision in the division.

My totalSize variable can exceed 2147483647 bytes, so I can't just set the progressbar max value as total size and increment the value by the file size.

Is there an easy way I can accomplish this? The only way I can think of is to just set the progressbar value to be 100% after the final element is done, but I want to avoid doing that if possible. Thanks

Comment: Do you think you could show us the code that processes the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things can be improved in your current design to represent better accuracy:

> My totalSize variable can exceed 2147483647 bytes, so I can't just set the progressbar max value as total size and increment the value by the file size.

1. Use `long` data type instead of `int`. This way, you can store the actual size of your data. The progress bar itself doesn't need to be as accurate as that, but:

   ```
   progress?.Report(pb.Value + (int)(update.Size * 100 / totalSize)); //note 100
   ```
2. You can actually improve the accuracy of the progress bar by adjusting its `progress.Maximum` to be higher (say, `progress.Maximum = 1000` then each `progress.Value` counts as 0.1% of the total) which will give you 10x more accuracy than the default progress bar settings, provided that your GUI supports such pixel accuracy.
3. Lastly,

> But, upon completion, the progressbar isn't full which I presume is
>   due to the loss of precision in the division.

It could be due to the mentioned reason, or...

1. It could be due to graphical representation. Since it takes a little delay for the progress bar graphics to be updated. It is possible that you have already finished your process and give right value to progress bar (that is 100/100 or 1000/1000 if you use my answer) but the UI isn't just updated yet. If you want to delay a little bit, simply use `Thread.Sleep`.
2. Also, another possible reason is that the rounding off is messed up somewhere, thus it gives you rounded off value which is a little off like `99/100`. To prevent this, I recommend to process the data using `double` instead of integer type before the final representation in `progress.Value = N;` assignment takes place. You could also consider using `Math.Round` if `double` precision still gives you very minor error. The important thing here is good debugging to isolate the cause, then we can apply appropriate fix.
3. Or it could also be due to the combined reasons above, in which you got to apply both fixes.

Comment: Ian, I'm really sorry that it's taken me so long to get back to you. I don't remember getting notification of your reply. Thanks so much for your reply, you made some excellent suggestions. I don't currently have the source to hand, but I will give it a go when I can.

Comment: @tom982 glad that it can be of any help! ;) no problem.